# How to set TTL (expiry) for json record in Redis OM .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

How can we set expiry for a record in dotnet using [Redis.OM dotnet](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/tutorials/stack-dotnet/) ?
I did go through documentation of Redis.OM dotnet but could not find any method that we can use to set expiry for a record. But for the same package using python ( [Redis OM Python](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/tutorials/stack-python/#setting-an-expiry-time-for-a-person) ) there is a method to set expiry.

```
person_to_expire = Person.get(id)
Person.db().expire(person_to_expire.key(), seconds)
```

Can someone help me to understand how we can do the similar thing using Redis OM dotnet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set TTL (Time to Live) during insert:

```
string _redisConnectionString = "redis://localhost:6379";
RedisConnectionProvider _provider = new RedisConnectionProvider(_redisConnectionString);
RedisCollection<Model.MyObject> _redisColl = (RedisCollection<Model.MyObject>)_provider.RedisCollection<Model.MyObject>();
var myObj = new Model.MyObject{id=1,name="My Name"};

_redisColl .InsertAsync(myObj, new TimeSpan(0,10,0)); //for 10 minutes TTL
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that you can set the TTL for InsertAsync(), but do we know what the best practice is for updating a TTL for an existing item, unfortunately SaveAsync() does not accept a TimeSpan argument.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the contributor of the package.

https://github.com/redis/redis-om-dotnet/issues/107

```
 private RedisConnectionProvider _provider = new RedisConnectionProvider("your connection string");
```

once the connection has been established and while inserting your record, you can use this method to set the expiration for the record.

```
_provider.Connection.Execute("EXPIRE", "your_key_for_the_record", "60");
```

Note: Here we need to pass seconds in string format.